# Cannot combine strings when they contain '{}' chars

Tags: c#, string

I am attempting to perform String Interpolation in C#. The input string I am attempting to combine contains many '{}' characters(because its javascript) which seems to be causing an error.

Why cant I perform string interpolation on these strings in C#?

```
string test = string.Format("{img: \"{0}\", html: \"{1}\"}", "images/a.png", "<div></div>");
// so the output should be
// "{img: \"images/a.png\", html: \"<div></div>\"}"
```

The error I get is:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

**Can you tell me how I can acheive my string interpolation?**

Comment: How is `string.Format` supposed to tell the difference between `{img:` and `{0` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Braces need to be escaped:

```
string test = string.Format("{{img: \"{0}\", html: \"{1}\"}}", "images/a.png", "<div></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Braces have special meaning to `string.Format`, so you need to escape them.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

There's no simple way to do what you want, but that documentation page suggests some workarounds.